# I would like to read plink files using pandas-plink in GC Datalab

Tags: python, pandas, google-cloud-datalab, plink

I am trying to figure out how to read plink files using `pandas-plink` in a GC Datalab notebook.

`pandas-plink` requires a variable containing the path/prefix to 3 plink files. (`file_prefix.bim`, `file_prefix.fam`, `file_prefix.bed`)

```
from pandas_plink import read_plink
(bim, fam, bed) = read_plink(gs://path/file_prefix)
```

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! I suppose that you forgot to describe your problem?